# Is it possible to install a library for Python without using the command line and the like?

Tags: python

For example, when starting the program, I want the libraries I need to download and install automatically without the user's help

Comment: `import library_name`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What research have you done? I don't have much experience with this myself, but have you considered bundling the dependencies with your program, or making a package with the dependencies specified? How about using `setuptools`? If I google `python automatically install dependencies` for example, I get results that look promising. For more tips, check out [How to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @D.L **Install**, not import. Consider NumPy for example: the most basic way to install it is on the command line with pip: `pip install numpy`.

Comment: Installation of prerequisites is really something you should do *once* when you *install* the script, not every time (or at least, checking if prerequisites are present) you *run* the script.

Comment: @chepner: agreed.  it would be rather time consuming doing this every time. And any "final version" would come as a package with the dependancies already there.